# Rails: dynamically generated path is adding a period and the id at the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, resources

I have the following:

```
# /config/routes.rb
resources :employees, :as => :firm_employments, :controller => :firm_employments do
  resource :user_account
end
```

However, I'm getting the following:

```
@firm_employment = FirmEmployment.find(1)
@user_account = @firm_employment.employee.user_account
firm_employment_user_account_path(@firm_employment, @user_account) # => '/employees/1/user_account.3'
```

Why is a period and the @user_account id being appended to this path? I'm trying to get it to return simply: "/employees/1/user_account"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If there's only one of a particular resource, then you don't pass in the id, as it's implicit:

```
firm_employment_user_account_path(@firm_employment)
```

What you're doing is supplying `@user_account` as the `:format` option, so of course it goes at the end after a period.

If you have more than one, you need to define the route differently:

```
resources :user_accounts
```

Comment: Just realized this, but you beat me to it! Thank you for the reply.